# Create a class that extends another custom class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, class, text

I have created class **Blabel** that extends **StatelessWidget**. I want to extend it to **Blabel1** , keeping **all of its properties** and **adding some extra properties** to it.

Let's say I would like to add `textDirection` property to the new class. How can I do it?

Here is the code of `Blabel` class that I have:

```
class Blabel extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  Blabel({
    this.text,
    this.style,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      text,
      style: style ?? CtrBlblStyle(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is something along the line of what you are looking for:

```
class Blabel1 extends Blabel {
  final TextDirection textDirection; // example of new property
  Blabel1({
    String text,
    TextStyle style,
    this.textDirection,
  }) : super(text: text, style: style);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // You can change the build method to change the UI from Blabe
    return Text(
      text,
      style: style ?? CtrBlblStyle(),
    );
  }
}
```